# Prisma transaction

Tags: node.js, next.js, orm, prisma

I'm trying to upsert and then from that result I have to go throw an array and upsert the values from another table

```
model ProductVariant {
  id              Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String           @db.VarChar(50)
  photos          Photo[]

  @@index([productId])
}
model Photo {
  id      String       @id @unique @db.VarChar(100)
  order   Int?         @default(0) @db.TinyInt
  visible PhotoVisible @default(Invisible)

  variantId Int
  variant   ProductVariant @relation(fields: [variantId], references: [id])

  @@index([variantId])
}
```

```
 return ctx.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
        input.variants.forEach((variant) => {
          tx.productVariant
            .upsert({
              where: {
                id: variant.id,
              },
              update: {
                name: variant.name,
              },
              create: {
                name: variant.name,
                productId: product.id,
              },
            })
            .then((variantOnDB) => {
              variant.photos?.forEach(async (photo) => {
                if (isBase64(photo.id)) {
                  const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo.id)
                  await tx.productVariant.update({
                    where: {
                      id: variantOnDB.id,
                    },
                    data: {
                      name: '',
                      photos: {
                        upsert: {
                          where: {
                            id: photo.id,
                          },
                          create: {
                            id: photo.id,
                            order: photo.order,
                          },
                          update: {
                            order: photo.order,
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  })
                }
              })
            })
        })
      })
    }),
```

and its giving me the following error message "Transaction already closed: Could not perform operation." does anyone know how can i fix this error or another way to make it

I'm expecting to make it work as I described

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the .forEach method to iterate over an array and perform asynchronous operations inside the loop, the loop doesn't wait for each asynchronous operation to complete before moving on to the next iteration. In your case, you are using .forEach to iterate over variant.photos and performing asynchronous operations inside that loop. Because of this, the transaction is not guaranteed to wait for all the asynchronous operations/callbacks to finish before it's closed. You need to replaced the .forEach loops with for...of loops to ensure that the await statements within the loops are awaited properly. May be try something like this instead?

```js
return ctx.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
  for (const variant of input.variants) {
    const variantOnDB = await tx.productVariant.upsert({
      where: {
        id: variant.id,
      },
      update: {
        name: variant.name,
      },
      create: {
        name: variant.name,
        productId: product.id,
      },
    })

    if (variant.photos) {
      for (const photo of variant.photos) {
        if (isBase64(photo.id)) {
          const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo.id)
          await tx.productVariant.update({
            where: {
              id: variantOnDB.id,
            },
            data: {
              name: '',
              photos: {
                upsert: {
                  where: {
                    id: photo.id,
                  },
                  create: {
                    id: photo.id,
                    order: photo.order,
                  },
                  update: {
                    order: photo.order,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```